# Not being able to use a variable defined in jQuery into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the variable 'value' to be printed using document.write() everytime a a color from drop down is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = 'xyz';

             $(document).ready(function(){ 
                  $('#button1').click(function(){ 
                    value = $('#combo').val();
                  alert (value);

                    });
        }); 

    </script>
<select id  = "combo">
    <option>White</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Fuchisa</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Silver</option>
    <option>Gray</option>
    <option>Olive</option>
</select>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />
<p><script type="text/javascript"> document.write(value) </script></p>
```

Comment: Why do you think that your current code does _anything_ when a color is selected from the dropdown? (Hint: **it doesn't.**) Go back and read the API docs: http://api.jquery.com. Also, you should rethink using `document.write()`, since this replaces the contents of the DOM when called after the document has been closed.

Comment: actually i'm trying to build a chart that has its color changed as per user selection. i need to pass the select item as a parameter to set color function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eek - dont use document.write

http://jsfiddle.net/2ahKH/

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    value = $('#combo').val();
    $('p').html(value);
});
```

Comment: actually i'm trying to build a chart that has its color changed as per user selection. i need to pass the select item as a parameter to set color() but it does not take the new value.

Comment: You can't use document.write to accomplish what you want.  Try this idea mrtsherman suggested - it will get you where you need to be.